# How to find first element at a specified height down the page with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm looking for the best way to find the first `img` element on my page that's at least 500px from the top. Is there a better way to do this than this selecting all `img` and querying the `.offset().top` of each ?

Comment: None that I can think of.  Have you tried looking at the source code behind some of the jQuery lazy-load plugins out there and see what they do?  That's what I'd do if no one else has a better technique than what you've already supplied.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a jQuery's `each` and return false to terminate execution of the loop early. This is the fastest way I can think of doing it. Keep in mind that images will be returned in order of the DOM. So if you had a sidebar and a center column with images then you may not get the first img > 500.

```
$('img').each( function() {
    if ($(this).offset().top > 500) {
        //do something
        ....
        //end each early
        return false;
    }
});
```